# get the dimensions of a swf file from a .NET Program

Tags: c#

is it possible to get the dimensions of a swf file from c#?

Comment: what is a swf video file? a Flash video file is a FLV, a swf can contain a video but it not an video on its own

Answer (score 2):

You should read the fileheader and retrieve the width and height:
[here is an example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ReaderSWFHeader.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Found [this one](http://jayakrishnagudla.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-get-width-and-height-of-swf-file.html) that works w/ latest Flash (10); supports compressed swf, too.

[Reader of SWF Header](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ReaderSWFHeader.aspx) returns a negative height for me; does not support compressed swf.